# using "IS" is better or checking for "NOT NULL"

Tags: coding-style, coding-standards

In C#.NET language: This style of coding is recommended or the one below it?

```
        if (sheet.Models.Data is GroupDataModel)
        {
            GroupDataModel gdm = (GroupDataModel)sheet.Models.Data;
            Group group = gdm.GetGroup(sheet.ActiveCell.Row.Index);   
            if (group!=null && controller != null)
            {
                controller.CheckApplicationState();
            }
        }
```

or this one:

```
        var gdm = sheet.Models.Data as GroupDataModel;
        if (gdm != null)
        {
            Group group = gdm.GetGroup(sheet.ActiveCell.Row.Index);   
            if (@group!=null && controller != null)
            {
                controller.CheckApplicationState();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/132445/102937

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you intend to cast (or use `as`) if the result of calling `is` is `true`, you should just call `as` and avoid two cast attempts.

I prefer the second version for this reason.

Comment: hmm what is that "@" that is being added in second version to the group variable? it is now @group

Comment: @BDotA - Looks like a typo to me.

Comment: wow! it still compiles fine with or with out "@"

Comment: @BDotA - The `@` before a variable name is ignored - it allows you to use reserved keywords as variable names. Like `var @class`, for instance.

Comment: The usage of `@` is called a verbatim identifier. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851540/c-sharp-operator-not-for-string-literals/11851563#11851563

Comment: FxCop will actually warn against casting twice in the first one

Answer (score 1):

**In short,** if you already know what type it can cast to **use a C-style** cast:

```
var o = (string) iKnowThisIsAString;
```

Note that only with a C-style cast can you perform explicit type coercion. If you don't know whether it's the desired type and you're going to use it if it is, use **as keyword:**

```
var txt = o as string;
if (txt != null) return txt.Replace("_","-");

//or for early return:
if (txt == null) return;
```

Note that **as** will not call any type conversion operators. It will only be non-null if the object is not null and natively of the specified type.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, they are two different things. But what do you think reads better?

```
if (sheet.Models.Data is GroupDataModel)
```

or

```
var gdm = sheet.Models.Data as GroupDataModel;
if (gdm != null)
```

You've got your answer here. Oded made a very valid point, but programming isn't much different from writing articles. It needs to be easily readable by other engineers.